# What are the values of $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the sequence $x_{n+1}=e^{x_n}-1$ is increasing?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a 2 part problem.

**1)** I am given the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 0}$ defined by the recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = e^{x_n}-1$ and we know that $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to find the values of $x_0$ for which the sequence is increasing. This is what I did:

We know that the sequence is increasing if $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} > 1$, so that means that we have:

$$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \dfrac{e^{x_n} - 1}{x_n} > 1$$

Which is satisfied when $x_n \in (0, + \infty)$. So, if we'd replace $n$ with $0$ (since the above inequality has to be satisfied for $0$ also) we'd have $x_0 \in (0, + \infty)$. So that means that the final answer would be $x_0 \in (0, +\infty)$. My question is, is this correct?

**2)** After this part of the problem, I am asked to find

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n$$

for $x_0 > 0$ (so for the values of $x_0$ from the previous part of the problem, **if** I did that part correctly). What I did here was to first prove by induction that

$$x_n > 0, \forall n \ge 0$$

And then again using the inequality from the previous part

$$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \dfrac{e^{x_n} - 1}{x_n} > 1$$

We know this is true because we have proved that $x_n > 0$, $\forall n \ge 0$. So this means that the sequence is monotonically increasing. That in turn means that the sequence has a finite limit or diverges towards $+ \infty$. Since know we know that the sequence is monotonic and has a limit (or diverges) we can jump staight to replacing the limit by a variable, like $L$:

$$x_{n+1} = e^{x_n} - 1$$

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_{n+1} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (e^{x_n} - 1)$$

$$L = L - 1$$

which can only happen if the limit is $+\infty$. So I concluded that:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = + \infty$$

Again, is this correct? I am new to the chapter of limits/sequences and it feels very sloppy. I want to make sure my thought process is correct.

Comment: Your ratio condition makes sense if $x_n>0$, but if it isn't then the inequality sign flips...what happens then? Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors. The exponential function satisfies the inequality
$$
 e^x \ge 1 + x
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R$, with equality only for $x = 0$. Use this to show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is strictly increasing if $x_0 \ne 0$ (and constant if $x_0 = 0$).

In any case, the sequence is either unbounded or convergent. If $x_n \to L$ then $e^L = 1 + L$, i.e. $L = 0$.

If $x_0 \le 0$ then $x_n \le 0$ for all $n$, so that the sequence is bounded, and $x_n \to 0$.

If $x_0 > 0$ then $x_n \to 0$ is not possible, so that the sequence is unbounded, i.e. $x_n \to \infty$.